# how give a default value at username field of User class in python

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

sorry my english is not very god. That is my problem.
i want give by default at username field the value of email field

This is my Member model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Member(User):

        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = 'Member'
```

[my serializer file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdafD.png)

thanks

Comment: In case user doesn't provide `username`, you want to use email as username. Right?

Comment: yes, i want use email

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your description. You can overwrite save method in model to make it so:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Member(User):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.username:
            self.username = self.email
        super(Member, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Member'
```

Comment: thanks for response but, he not work. i have this message ""username":["This field is required."]}"

Comment: So add `required=False` for the field `username` in your `serializer`.

Comment: thanks for response but, i want the username to have the value of the email. if i use your method, it will not work because the usernames can't have the same value.

Comment: Did you allow user use same emails? If not, username by email must be unique.

Comment: the default username must be the email. so if a user registers and does not put his username, then by default the username field will hang the value of the email.